# How to get the user preferred units? Meters or Miles

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am developing an app in react native and I would like to display some distance to my users.

As I live in Europe, I have used the "Kilometers" systems but I would like to know my user settings for this metrics so I could display the value with the correct unit.

I already used this module : https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info

But it does not seem to have this functionality.

Do you know some module that have?
Or a quick way to link some native function?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could use `getDeviceCountry()` with `react-native-device-info`, there's only a few countries that use miles so you could hardcode checking for those countries

Comment: Something good to know is that most of countries use metric system. While UK and US have still imperial units for road distances, they uses metric system in most cases (science, engineering, medicine, defence...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested in the comments, you ca use `react-native-device-info`. 
See below, for a working example:

```
  transformDistance(distanceKM) {
    const countryCode = DeviceInfo.getDeviceCountry(); // get country code 
    const factor = 0.621371; // constant scale factor: 1km = 0.621371 miles
    if (countryCode == "US") {
      return <Text> {distanceKM * factor} Miles </Text>;
    } 
    // add other countries as additional if statements here 
    //

    //otherwise return distance in metric unit
    return <Text> {distanceKM} Km </Text>;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
     {this.transformDistance(5)} // outputs 3.106855 Miles or 5 Km
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tips ! I will check the country list on google to add more than US if needed :)